# implement sound into shake?

Tags: android, sdk, shake

I am guessing that it would be a shake listener of some sort. but what I want to do is have the sound play when I shake the phone. could some one help? I know that there is a way I see them all the time. Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, write a service to use device sensors data to figure out a shake. And if it does so, play a sound.